# sed return multiple next-word results on one string

Tags: sed

Is it possible to return multiple next word results using a single sed query

String:

```
profile string.www.com { app-service none cert string.www.com_2018_2020.crt cert-key-chain { string.www.com _2018_2020_geotrust_rsa_ca_2018 { cert string.www.com _2018_2020.crt chain geotrust_rsa_ca_2018.crt key string.www.com_2018_2020.key } } chain geotrust_rsa_ca_2018.crt defaults-from default-clientssl inherit-certkeychain false key string.www.com_2018_2020.key passphrase none }
```

So for instance something like:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(profile \|defaults-from \| passphrase) \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Would return:

```
string.www.com
default-clientssl
none
```

Comment: No, `sed` patterns are always "greedy". You need `grep`. Something like `grep -oP '(profile|defaults-from|passphrase) \K\S+'`. See [this regex demo](https://ideone.com/xMr033).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily extract multiple matches on the same line with `sed` as its patterns are always "greedy". You may do it with two steps:

```
sed 's/\(profile\|defaults-from\|passphrase\) \([^ ]*\)/\nXXX\2XXX\n/g' <<< "$s" | \
 sed -n 's/^XXX\(.*\)XXX$/\1/p'
```

First, wrap the matches with `XXX` and newlines, and then grab those matches with `sed -n 's/^XXX\(.*\)XXX$/\1/p'`. See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/c43Wva).

If you want a "sngle-step" solution, you can extract those texts much easier with `grep`.

GNU grep solution:

```
grep -oP '(profile|defaults-from|passphrase)\s+\K\S+' file
```

Or, with `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -o '(profile|defaults-from|passphrase)\s+\K\S+' file
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/xMr033).

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/\n/!s/(profile|defaults-from|passphrase) \S+/\n&\n/g;/^(profile|defaults-from|passphrase)/P;D' file
```

Surround the required keys and values by newlines and only print those keys and values when they present themselves at the start of the line.

To output only the value:

```
sed -En '/\n/!s/(profile|defaults-from|passphrase) \S+/\n&\n/g;/^(profile|defaults-from|passphrase)/{s/\S+ //;P};D' file
```

Comment: However, this [outputs](https://ideone.com/t79iR1) more than OP expects (output contains the left-hand context).

Comment: Now, it works, but still, that is not a single command. I also posted a two-step `sed` solution in my answer half an hour ago.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP said " Is it possible to return multiple next word results using a single sed query" not a single sed command.

Comment: From what I understand `;` are separating `sed` **commands**, see [*3.8 Multiple commands syntax*](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html): *A semicolon (‘;’) may be used to separate most simple commands*. Not sure that is all relevant though, since it still means several "steps".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP never uses the word **command** but  says ` a single sed query`. A **query** as I understand the term in this situation , is a request for information using a single invocation of the program sed. Your sed solution/workaround uses two invocations, connected by a unix pipe.